# What are the limit points of $A_n=[n,\infty)$ in a metric space? Is $A_n$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, infinity

$A_n=[n,\infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with a Euclidean metric.

A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. A limit point is a point whose neighborhood contains a point in the set. I'm not sure what happens when we consider a neighborhood at infinity.

Is $A_n$ the set of limit points of $A_n$? If this is true, $A_n$ is closed.

Comment: Which metric space? $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric?

Comment: Yes, $A_n$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of "limit point" is wrong. The expression "a point whose neighbourbood" makes no sense, since a point generally has more than one neighbourhood. Also, the point contained in the neighbourhood may not be the point itself. Rather, a limit point of a set is a point $x$ *each* of whose neighbourhoods contains a point in the set *other than* $x$.

It's also not entirely clear what you mean by "a neighbourhood at infinity". You may be confused by the notation $[n,\infty)$. Here the symbol $\infty$ is a notational device and not an element of $\mathbb R$. Points in $\mathbb R$ have "neighbourhoods at infinity" in the sense that that they have neighbourhoods that extend to infinity, but this is irrelevant here since whether a point is a limit point is decided "at close range": Since every superset of a neighbourhood contains all points of the neighbourhood, the condition that *every* neighbourhood must contain a point means that *every arbitrarily small neighbourhood* must contain a point.

In the present case, almost all points $x\in A_n$ are in the interior of $A_n$ and have entire neighbourhoods within $A_n$ (for instance $(\frac{x+n}2,\infty)$), except for $x=n$, but here, too, every neighbourhood contains an open set $(n-\epsilon,n+\epsilon)$, which contains the point $n+\frac\epsilon2\in A_n$.

Comment: The concept of "neighbourhood of infinity" does make sense if you define it as $(M,\infty)$, for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @ryagami: The post says "neighbourhood at infinity", not "neighbourhood of infinity"; that was part of the vagueness I was referring to. Also, I didn't say that this expression doesn't make sense, just that it's not entirely clear what's meant. The term "neighbourhood of infinity" is well-defined if infinity is an element of the set; if it isn't, we can guess that the intended meaning is "add infinity to the set, take a neighbourhood of it and remove infinity from it".